# How do I iterate over my sheet and color in cells that meet a specific condition? Using Python and openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, colors, openpyxl, fill

I want to iterate over a sheet and fill in cells if the cell is not 'empty'/null
if the cell is empty then no action required
if the cell is !empty, then color (fill) it in

the error message is

> ```
> sheet[i].fill = PatternFill(fill_type='solid', start_color='43e33b', end_color='43e33b')
> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'fill'
> ```

The code I'm using is

```
import openpyxl as xl

from openpyxl.styles import Font, Fill, Color, colors, PatternFill

# creating a variable to take any filename input from user
filename = input('Enter filename here: ')

# loading workbook on local computer c drive using filename
wb = xl.load_workbook(f'c:\\Users\\Charlie\\Desktop\\{filename}.xlsx')

# working with sheet1 on wb 'workbook'
sheet = wb['Sheet1']


# defining pacing list function
def packing_list():
    # deleting columns so that columns required are left for new file
    sheet.delete_cols(1, 14)
    max_rows = sheet.max_row
    print(max_rows)
    for i in range(1, max_rows):
        if sheet.cell(column=7, row=i, value=""):
            sheet[i].fill = PatternFill(fill_type='solid', 
            start_color='43e33b', end_color='43e33b')
        else:
            break
    # saving new worksheet to desktop with name packing_list
    wb.save('c:\\Users\\Charlie\\Desktop\\packing_list.xlsx')
```

Comment: That partly worked for me thank you.
What is happening now is it's removing the value of each cell in row 6 to nothing. I need to iterate over the cell condition and if it does hold any value, then color it in (with the text still showing) the Fill color I'm using is filling in the whole cell and removing its contents.
I'm also new to openpyxl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sheet[i]` is a tuple containing all the cells in the `i`th row, where i >= 1

`sheet[i][j]` is the `i,j`th cell, where j >= 0. So the 7th column would be `sheet[i][6]`.

You could get the same thing using `sheet.cell(column=7, row=i)`, where both row and column are 1-based.

You should be able to set `sheet.cell(column=7, row=i).fill` without any problems

Comment: see above comment

Comment: _" I'm also new to openpyxl"_ So am I. I installed the library so I could answer this question. [Read the documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.cell). It tells you that when you call `worksheet.cell()`, with a `value`, it sets that cell's value and returns the object for that cell. If you call it without a value, it just returns the object. Once you have the cell, you can check its value and set the fill if needed.